# MYSQL HAVING STATEMENT AND CALCULATION ISSUE

Tags: mysql, having

What is wrong in this mySQL statement?

I check for the max value of ***C_BATCH_ID*** in ***batch*** table and then compare it to the value extracted from a reference (***C_KEY***)

It returns nothing while if I replace ***MAX( C_BATCH_ID )*** by a value such as ***23*** it returns n records.

```
SELECT
    contract.KEY AS C_KEY,
    contract.BATCH_ID AS C_BATCH_ID,
    contract.CUSTOMER_NAME as C_NAME,
    batch.BATCH_ID = B_BATCH_ID
FROM
    contract
INNER JOIN 
    batch ON contract.BATCH_ID = batch.BATCH_ID 
HAVING
    SUBSTRING_INDEX( C_KEY, '-', 1 ) = MAX( B_BATCH_ID )
ORDER BY
    contract.CUSTOMER_NAME
```

Thanks for your help. :)

contract table

| id | C_KEY | C_BATCH_ID | C_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10-KEY01 | 10 | Customer 1 |
| 2 | 23-KEY01 | 23 | Customer 2 |
| 3 | 23-KEY02 | 23 | Customer 3 |
| 4 | 12-KEY01 | 12 | Customer 2 |
| 5 | 23-KEY03 | 23 | Customer 4 |

batch table

| B_BATCH_ID | BATCH_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Batch 1 |
| 2 | Batch 2 |
| 3 | Batch 3 |
| 4 | Batch 4 |
| 10 | Batch 10 |
| 12 | Batch 12 |
| 23 | Batch 23 |

Desired result as 23 is the max value of B_BATCH_ID:

| id | C_KEY | C_BATCH_ID | C_NAME | B_BATCH_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 23-KEY01 | 23 | Customer 2 | 23 |
| 3 | 23-KEY02 | 23 | Customer 3 | 23 |
| 5 | 23-KEY03 | 23 | Customer 4 | 23 |

Comment: MAX(C_BATCH_ID) does return a calculated value if integrated to the SELECT

Comment: Your query is malformed. There are columns in the list of selected columns that neither are in the `GROUP BY` clause nor an argument to an aggregation function. Sadly instances of old MySQL versions or badly configured ones accept such erroneous queries. But the result can suddenly be funny.

Comment: I honnestly do not understand why I should need a GROUP BY

Comment: Because you use an aggregation function. Without a `GROUP BY` the whole table is the single group. But then it makes no sense to project any other columns.

Comment: Either way, [edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables and/or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites, make sure the statements are complete and compile, don't post just mere snippets), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data as ASCII or markdown table (see ["How can I create a table in a post?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post)).

Comment: Thanks. Pleaser find the data model.

Comment: Could using `where` instead of `having` solve your problem?

Comment: Answer to myself: actually not beacuse you are using `max`. Max batch_id should be likely get separately

Comment: The column names in the tables don't match those in the query. And what is `B_BATCH_ID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get `MAX(BATCH_ID)` in sub-query. Solution could be like this:

```
SELECT
    contract.KEY AS C_KEY,
    contract.BATCH_ID AS C_BATCH_ID,
    contract.CUSTOMER_NAME as C_NAME
FROM
    contract
WHERE
    SUBSTRING_INDEX( contract.KEY, '-', 1 ) = (SELECT MAX(BATCH_ID) FROM batch)
ORDER BY
    contract.CUSTOMER_NAME
```

Base on example data `contract.BATCH_ID` could be used instead of `SUBSTRING_INDEX( contract.KEY, '-', 1 )` but not sure if there is a reason for this in real data

Comment: SUBSTRING_INDEX( contract.KEY, '-', 1 ) makes sense for what I need in the process. But thanks anyway as the sub-query is the right solution :)

Comment: A big than you to all contributors !!!!